# LibreOffice/other method of filling template .txt file for import into Zim Wiki

Tags: python, linux, database, wiki, libreoffice

I am using the application Zim Wiki(cross-platform, FOSS), which I am using to keep a personal wiki with lots of data coming from tables, copy and pasting, my own writing, and downloading and attaching .png and .html files for viewing and offline access.

The data that is not written or pasted can be stored in tables in the form of names, url addresses, and the names and locations of images and other attachments.

To insert into zim, I can use the front end with WSIWYG, or to make the skeleton of each entry, I could modify a template text entry.  If I do this, nothing matters except for the location and identity of each character in each line.

By supplying the text in this image:
[DandelionDemo source text](https://postimg.org/image/fobdpwfvf/),

--I can make this entry for Dandelion:
[DandelionDemo Wiki](https://postimg.org/image/q9v91zm7v/).

So, I can generate and name the Wiki entry in Zim, which creates the .txt file for me, and inserts the time stamp and title, so, the template for this type of entry without the pasted fields would be:

```
**Full Scientific Name:   **[[|]]**[syn]**
**Common Name(s): **
=====  =====
**USDA PLANTS entry for Code:** [[https://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=|]]   **-   CalPhotos available images for:** [[https://calphotos.berkeley.edu/cgi/img_query?query_src=photos_index&where-taxon=|]]
**---**
**From - Wikipedia **[[wp?]]   **-   **[[/Docs/Plants/]] 
{{/Docs/Plants/?height=364}}{{/Docs/Plants/?height=364}}
**()** //,// [[|(source)]]
**()** //// [[|(source)]]
**Wikipedia Intro:  **////
---
```

So the first line with content, after the 31st character(which is a tab), you paste "http... {etc}. Then the procedure would insert "Taraxacum officinale... {etc}" after the "|", or what was the 32nd character, and so on.  This data could be from "table1" and "table2", or combining the tables to make an un-normalized "table1table2", where each row could be converted to text or a .csv or I don't know, what do you think?

Is there a way, in LibreOffice to do this?  I have used LibreOffice Base to generate a "book" form that populated fields, but it was much less complex data, without wiki liking and drag-and-drop pasting of images and attachments.  So maybe the answer is to go simpler?  The tables are not currently part of a registered database, but I could do that, once I have decided on the method of doing this.

I am ultimately looking for a "way", hopefully an "easy" way.  However, that may not be in LibreOffice.  If not, I know that I could do this in Python, but I haven't learned much about Python yet.  If it involves a language, that is the first and only one I don't know that I will invest in learning for this project.  If you know a "way" to do this in Python, let me know, and my first project and way of framing my study process will be in learning the methods that you share.

If you know of some other Linux GUI, I am definitely interested, but only in active free and open source builds that involve minimal/no compiling.  I know the basics of SQL and DBMS's.  In the past, have gotten Microsoft SQL server lite to work, but not DBeaver, yet.  If you know of a CLI way also let me know, but I am a self-taught outdoors-loving Linux newb and mostly know about how to tweak little settings in programs, how to use moderately easy programs like ImageMagick, and I have built a few Lamp stacks for Drupal and Wordpress (no BASH etc...).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you want to learn some python, let me propose you a way to do it this. First you need a template engine -like [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) (there are many others)-, a data source in our example a .csv file, -could be other like a db- and finally some code that reads the csv line by line and mix the content with the template.

**Sample CSV file**:

```csv
1;sample
2;dandelion
3;just for fun
```

**Sample template**:

```txt
**Full Scientific Name:   **[[|]]**[syn]**
**Common Name(s): *{{name}}*
=====  =====
USDA PLANTS entry for Code: *{{symbol}}*
---
```

**Sample code**:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env/python
#
# Using the file system load
#
# We now assume we have a file in the same dir as this one called
# test_template.ziim
#

from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import os
import csv

# Capture our current directory
THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


def print_zim_doc():
    # Create the jinja2 environment.
    # Notice the use of trim_blocks, which greatly helps control whitespace.
    j2_env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(THIS_DIR),
                         trim_blocks=True)

    template = j2_env.get_template('test_template.zim')
    with open('example.csv') as File:
        reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=';')
        for row in reader:
            result = template.render(
                symbol=row[0]
                , name=row[1]
            )
            # to save the results
            with open(row[0]+".txt", "wt") as fh:
                fh.write(result)
            fh.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_zim_doc()
```

The code is pretty simple, reads the template located in the same folder as the python code, opens the csv file (also located in the same place), iterates over each line of the csv and renders the template using the values of the csv columns to fill the {{var_name}} in the template, finally saves the rendered result in a new file named as one of the csv column values. This sample will generate 3 files (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt). From here you can extend and improve the code to get your desired results.